# convert 2D dataframe to 3D dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2D dataframe with shape of (16422,28) as follow:

```
df= 
        id     var0    var1    var2    var3    var4 ...  var27
        5171   10.0    2.8     0.0     5.0     1.0  ...  9.4  
        5171   40.9    2.5     3.4     4.5     1.3  ...  7.7  
        5171   60.7    3.1     5.2     6.6     3.4  ...  1.0
        ...
        5171   0.5     1.3     5.1     0.5     0.2  ...  0.4
        4567   1.5     2.0     1.0     4.5     0.1  ...  0.4  
        4567   4.4     2.0     1.3     6.4     0.1  ...  3.3  
        4567   6.3     3.0     1.5     7.6     1.6  ...  1.6
        ...
        4567   0.7     1.4     1.4     0.3     4.2  ...  1.7
       ... 
        9584   0.3     2.6     0.0     5.2     1.6  ...  9.7  
        9584   0.5     1.2     8.3     3.4     1.3  ...  1.7  
        9584   0.7     3.0     5.6     6.6     3.0  ...  1.0
        ...
        9584   0.7     1.3     0.1     0.0     2.0  ...  1.7
```

I need to convert it to a 3D dataframe of shape (16422,28,1). The following will give me a 3D ndarray:

```
values_3d = df.values.reshape(df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 1)
```

I tried to use pd.Panel() to convert this ndarray to 3d dataframe:

```
tmp = pd.Panel(values_3d,  major_axis=df.index, minor_axis=df.columns)
```

but it complains that `TypeError: Panel() takes no argument`. Then I tried to create 3D dataframe with multilevel index as follow:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(values_3d, columns=df.columns
                , index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(np.arange(start=0, stop=values_3d.shape[0]), df.index))
```

and it gives me this error: `TypeError: Input must be list-like`

How can I do this reshape?

Comment: `Panel` has been deprecated.  You shouldn't be using it for this purpose.  If you want an n-dimensional Pandas object, utilize the `MultiIndex` for either the index or columns.  More specifically, you don't need a 3-d array to form with a `MultiIndex`

Answer (score 0):

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
data_2d = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 5))
df_2d = pd.DataFrame(data_2d).add_prefix('var')

df_2d

   var0  var1  var2  var3  var4
0     0     2     7     3     8
1     7     0     6     8     6
2     0     2     0     4     9
3     7     3     2     4     3
4     3     6     7     7     4
5     5     3     7     5     9
6     8     7     6     4     7
7     6     2     6     6     5
8     2     8     7     5     8
9     4     7     6     1     5
```

---

#### `pd.concat`

It appears you want to add a dimension of length 1.

Along `axis=0`:

```
# This will be the index label
#           ↓
pd.concat({'label': df_2d})

         var0  var1  var2  var3  var4
label 0     0     2     7     3     8
      1     7     0     6     8     6
      2     0     2     0     4     9
      3     7     3     2     4     3
      4     3     6     7     7     4
      5     5     3     7     5     9
      6     8     7     6     4     7
      7     6     2     6     6     5
      8     2     8     7     5     8
      9     4     7     6     1     5
```

You can label the new index level

```
#                This is the name of the index level
# This will be the index label      │
#           ↓                       ↓
pd.concat({'label': df_2d}, names=['name_of_level'])

                 var0  var1  var2  var3  var4
name_of_level                                
label         0     0     2     7     3     8
              1     7     0     6     8     6
              2     0     2     0     4     9
              3     7     3     2     4     3
              4     3     6     7     7     4
              5     5     3     7     5     9
              6     8     7     6     4     7
              7     6     2     6     6     5
              8     2     8     7     5     8
              9     4     7     6     1     5
```

Along `axis=1`

```
# This will be the index label
#           ↓
pd.concat({'label': df_2d}, axis=1)    

  label                    
   var0 var1 var2 var3 var4
0     0    2    7    3    8
1     7    0    6    8    6
2     0    2    0    4    9
3     7    3    2    4    3
4     3    6    7    7    4
5     5    3    7    5    9
6     8    7    6    4    7
7     6    2    6    6    5
8     2    8    7    5    8
9     4    7    6    1    5
```